# Mouse events on SVG defs (mask)

Tags: javascript, svg

[image: svg mouse events in defs]

There is svg over background image. SVG is a square with a round hole in the middle (as an example). A background image appears through the circle.

I want  to drag this circle by the mouse. But how to get access from javascript to defs inside svg is not clear. I can change properties, but onclick events do not work on them.

Here is my SVG, and I want to access mouse events on element with `id = my_mask`:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="hole">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
      <g id="my_mask">
        <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100" fill="#000"/>
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
<rect fill="#00f" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#hole)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

On `mousemove` you reset the `cx` and `cy` attributes of the circle. I hope this is what you were asking.

```js
//on `mousemove` you reset the `cx` and `cy` attributes of the circle
svg.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>{
  let m = oMousePosSVG(e)
  c.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",m.x)
  c.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",m.y)
})

// a function to get the position of the mouse over the svg canvas
function oMousePosSVG(e) {
      var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
      p.x = e.clientX;
      p.y = e.clientY;
      var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
      var p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);
      return p;
}
```

```css
svg{background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg); background-size:cover}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<defs>
<mask id="hole">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
<g id="my_mask">
<circle id="c" r="50" cx="100" cy="100" fill="#000"/>
</g>
</mask>
</defs>
<rect fill="#00f" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#hole)" />
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

You cannot attach an event to a mask however you can use the circle inside the mask and attach an event to the use as I do in the next example:

In this example I'm using the `mousedown` event but you van use `mouseover` instead.

```js
let m,dx,dy;
let dragging = false;

theUse.addEventListener("mousedown",(e)=>{
  m = oMousePosSVG(e);
  dx = Number(c.getAttribute("cx")) - m.x;
  dy = Number(c.getAttribute("cy")) - m.y;
  dragging = true;
})

svg.addEventListener("mouseup",(e)=>{
  
  dragging = false;
})


svg.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>{
  if(dragging){
  m = oMousePosSVG(e)
  c.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",m.x + dx)
  c.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",m.y + dy)
  }
})


function oMousePosSVG(e) {
      var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
      p.x = e.clientX;
      p.y = e.clientY;
      var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
      var p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);
      return p;
}
```

```css
svg{background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg); background-size:cover}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<defs>
<mask id="hole">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
<g id="my_mask">
<circle id="c" r="50" cx="100" cy="100" />
</g>
</mask>
</defs>
<rect fill="#00f" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#hole)" />
  
  
<use id="theUse" xlink:href="#c" fill="none" pointer-events="all" />
</svg>
```

Comment: There can be several circles in a task. I can track them by coordinates, but the question was not about that. I need a code like this: my_mask.onmouseover = function ...

Comment: @enxaneta Good helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following variant with help of `d3.js` but this effect can be achieved without d3 too:

[image: example]

Here is a another transparent circle with drag possibility and position sync with masking circle when dragging, try it live snippet:

```js
let d = [[100,100,50], [300,100,40], [500,100,30]]
         .map(d=>({x: d[0], y: d[1], r: d[2]}));
let mask = circles('mask').call(upd);
  
circles('g').style('fill','transparent')
  .style('cursor','pointer')
  .call(upd)
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", function (d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
    mask.call(upd)  
  }));

function circles(selector) {
  return d3.select(selector)
           .selectAll('circle')
           .data(d)
           .enter()
           .append('circle')
}

function upd(selection) {
   selection.attr("cx", d => d.x)
            .attr("cy", d => d.y)
            .attr('r',  d => d.r);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" style="background: center url(https://i.imgur.com/cdqfoqZ.png)">
<defs>
  <mask id="hole">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
  </mask>
</defs>
<rect fill="#00f" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#hole)" />
<g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @IvanTitov i where added example with multiple circles =)

Comment: Thanks! I knew about the solution with the ghost circle ) So, your answer is - there is no direct access to defs-element?

Comment: @IvanTitov exactly

Comment: Here is a code of my the same solution on actionscript 2.0 (flash) in 2011. The mask-circle is updated in each frame in accordance with the ghost-circle =)
`_root.onEnterFrame = function() {
if (moving) {
akt.vot._x = trans.over["krug"+a]._x;
akt.vot._y = trans.over["krug"+a]._y;
}`

Comment: @IvanTitov krug :) you also can found us at stackoverflow on russian

Comment: I thought that on the international version of the site, secrets of SVG would be revealed to me ) But I was answered by a Russian programmer. And... Ba-dum-tss! His solution is the same as I had invented sometime ) Still, we are smart rebyata )))